# How to keep track of password ages using samba?

Tags: windows, password, samba

I am using Fedora 24 and Samba version is 4.4.5. I have configured samba using authentication mode as User. Also, recently I changed samba password using `smbpasswd -r domainname -U username` this changes the password for windows domain account.

Note that I have different user on Linux and Windows domain account and I already tried `pdbedit` command with no luck.

`sudo pdbedit -L -v` command gives no oputput.

Is there any command by which we can get information about password age?

Edit:

My office laptop is dual boot system which has Windows 2007 and Fedora in dual boot. Whenever I login using Windows 2007 I get authenticated using Windows Domain in our office environment but in case of Fedora account is local and doesn't get authenticated at the time of login.

So, in order to access Windows Share environment I have installed samba client and change smb.conf as per my Domain account.

Now the problem is I am able to access share through samba command, also able to change domain account password but not able to get password age associated with that account.

Comment: Specify how you configured samba to manage users. Are they using UNIX users?

Comment: Please check my Edit.